# Entity Framework 6 giving adding _id to column in foreign table and can't see why?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, foreign-keys

I've already got a lot of table relationships setup, and working succesfully, in the code already. EF6 is generating a column in the SQL statement that doesn't exist in the table which is part of a foreign key relationship.

Here are the two tables.  The relationship is that Process can have many AlloyTreatmentProcess records.  The tables in the database are fine. Code below...

This is the first time posting on here, so thanks in Advance...this is driving me nuts...EF6   8-(

```
public class AlloyTreatmentProcess
{

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? AlloyTreatmentID { get; set; }
    public int? ProcessID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("AlloyTreatmentID")]
    public virtual AlloyTreatment AlloyTreatment { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ProcessID")]
    public virtual Process Process { get; set; }

}

public Process()
    {
       this.AlloyTreatmentProcess = new HashSet<AlloyTreatmentProcess>();
    }
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }
    //navigation properties
    public virtual ICollection<AlloyTreatmentProcess> AlloyTreatmentProcess { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that there was nothing wrong with the joins at all in the end.  The real issue was I retrieved records for the AlloyTreatmentProcess but need to "Include" the process records.
e.g.

```
var list = db.AlloyTreatmentProcess.Where( a => a.AlloyTreatmentID == 1);
```

I needed to add a .Include

e.g.

```
var list = db.AlloyTreatmentProess.Where( a => a.AlloyTreatmentID == 1).Include(a => a.Process);
```

Apologies if this has lost anyone any time.
Thanks

Love EF at times...and at other times not!